# Static linking in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking

I've created an application using Qt in C++, the problem is that I need to statically link the  dependencies within the executable and I don't really know how.

I've performed the following steps:

- Added the -static flag to QMAKE_LFLAGS in qmake.conf
- Recompiled the Qt sources
- Added the new compiler in Qt Creator [created a kit containing my qt version and added it in the Projects Tab]
- When I try to build my application, or even an example from Qt Creator, I receive the following output:

  18:04:10: Running steps for project test...
  18:04:10: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\Src\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe" C:\my\qt\test\test.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
  Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkit webkitwidgets widgets gui core
  18:04:10: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\Src\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 3.
  Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Static Kit)
  When executing step 'qmake'
  18:04:10: Elapsed time: 00:00.

I guess I need to recompile with the dependencies listed in the error. Am I on the right track?
It's the first time I'm doing static linking and I would appreciate input.